# Highlight Html tags in a string

Tags: javascript, html, angular

How to highlight html tags in string?
e.g.
I have this type of string

**This is a html string `&lt;span id="name"&gt;` these texts are outside the tag**

so you can see the above string contains html tags, I need to wrap those html tags with a italic tag something like the below example, how do I do that?

**This is a html string `<i class="bg-dark">&lt;span id="name"&gt;</i>` these texts are outside the tag**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good way to do that, create a new pipe, in the pipe you can configure a regex to catch html tags to rewrite it and return a simple html string with custom style, Lastly you need to use [innerHTML] in your .html file as follows:

```
<p [innerHTML] = 'Your text | htmlPipeDetector' ></p>
```

Simple example to follow up with custom pipes and usage:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/linkify-pipe?file=app%2Flinkify.pipe.ts

Simple html regular expression:

```
const htmlRegex: RegExp = /<.+>/g;
```

Pipe example:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Pipe({
  name: 'htmlPipeDetector'
})
export class htmlPipeDetectorPipe implements PipeTransform {

  // tslint:disable-next-line: variable-name
  constructor(private _domSanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }


transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
    return this._domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(this.stylize(value));
  }

  // Modify this method according to your custom logic
  private stylize(text: string): string {
    if (text && text.length > 0) {
      return this.HTMLHighlighter(text);
    }

    return text;
  }


  HTMLHighlighter(text: string) {
      // using custom style
    const style = 'cursor: pointer;color: blue;text-decoration: underline;';
    const list = this.extractHTMLTags(text);
    if (list) {
      for (const element of list) {
        if (!element) {
          continue;
        }
        text = text.replace(element,
          `<i class='bg-dark' style='${style}'>${element}</i>`);
      }
    }
    return text;
  }

  extractHTMLTags(text): string[] {

    const htmlRegex: RegExp = /<.+>(.*?)<\/.+>/g;
    
    const list = htmlRegex.exec(text);
    // add any function to alter extracted tags like for e.g. removing tags etc...
    return list;
  }

 }
```

Make sure the regex is working as suits you.

Comment: I wan't to surround only html tags with an italic tag in a string

Comment: answer updated.